# Loading image and button disabling is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I am trying to disable a button after clicking and want to show a processing image,
but it is not working. My code is below:

```
$('#own_message_post').ajaxForm(function(data) {

    $("#loading_img").css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#submit_form_button').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#own_message_post').append('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="posting" id="message_post_loading_img" style="text-align: center"/>'); 
    $('#messages').prepend(data);
    $('#text_message').val("");
    $('#fileupload').val("");
    $('#submit_form_button').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#message_post_loading_img').remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using `ajaxForm` correctly, it accepts an [`Options Object`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object), you are passing it a `function` instead.

What would work in your case would be something like:

```
$('#own_message_post').ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function() {
    // Here you can do the things that need doing before the form is submitted
    $('#submit_form_button').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#own_message_post').append('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="posting" id="message_post_loading_img" style="text-align: center"/>');
  },
  success: function(){
    // Here you can do the things that need doing when all is done
    $('#submit_form_button').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#message_post_loading_img').remove();
  }
});
```

Since it looks like you are uploading a file, it might be useful to have a look at the `uploadProgress` callback as well, which could pass you back information about the progress of the upload.

Answer (score 0):

use prop() as of jquery 1.6

```
  $('#submit_form_button').prop("disabled", true);
```

and

```
 $('#submit_form_button').prop("disabled", false);
```

instead of

```
$('#submit_form_button').removeAttr('disabled');
```